# Deserialization soap response C#

Tags: c#, soap, deserialization, message

I get a soap response from the service:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getCurrencyListResponse>
        <getCurrencyListReturn SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">18</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">USD</value>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">19</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">EUR</value>
                </item>
            </item>
        </getCurrencyListReturn>
    </ns1:getCurrencyListResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

File wsdl does not specify a return type. How can I deserializing this messages in C#? The number of "item" and "Map" is not know. Should be similar to this example:

```
[SoapType(Namespace = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap", TypeName = "Map")]
public class Map
{
    public item[] item;
}

public class item
{
    [SoapElement]
    public string key;

    [SoapElement]
    public string value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your project you should add a reference to webservice.
In this way a wrapper for webservice is automatically created, letting you call its methods and getting responses using classes inside wrapper.
Serialization and deserialization are transparent to you.

Comment: This is a broblem. File wsdl does not specify a return type. I want to describe it myself.